# default value for entity widget in a formbuilder

Tags: forms, symfony, widget, entity, default-value

I have seen a lot of topics concerning how to set default data on a form in Symfony2, but I didn't find anything about how to set default data in an entity widget with a query builder. I explain my problem :

I have two entities, communication and Status, with a relation ManyToOne. 
Here is my Communication class :

```
class Communication{

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="Comm_CommunicationId")
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
protected $id;

    /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Test\DatabaseBundle\Entity\Statut", inversedBy="communication")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Comm_Status", referencedColumnName="Capt_Code")
 */
private $statut;}
```

And here is my Status class:

```
class Statut{

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="Capt_CaptionId")
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
protected $id;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="Capt_Code", type="string")
 */
private $code;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="Capt_FR", type="string")
 */
private $codefr;}
```

I have built a CommunicationType form to allow me to modify a communication entity:

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder      -> add('caseid','text')
                  -> add('statut','entity', array('class' => 'Test\DatabaseBundle\Entity\Statut',
                                                  'query_builder' => function(\Test\DatabaseBundle\Entity\StatutRepository $sr){
                                                        $res = $sr->getCodeOnly();                                                          
                                                        return $res; },
                                                  'property' => 'CodeFr',
                                                  'preferred_choices' => array(1),
                                                  ));}
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function ModifierAction($commid){
    $comm = $this -> getDoctrine()
                  -> getEntityManager()
                  -> getRepository('Test\DatabaseBundle\Entity\Communication')
                  -> find($commid);
    $form = $this -> createForm(new CommunicationType($em), $comm);
    ....
}
```

I give you the setter and the getter of my entities :
communication :

```
/**
 * Set id
 *
 * @param integer $Id
 */
public function setId($Id)
{
    $this -> id = $Id;
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}
```

Status entity :

```
/**
 * Set id
 *
 * @param integer $id
 */
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}       /**
 * Set code
 *
 * @param string $code
 */
public function setCode($code)
{
    $this->code = $code;
}

/**
 * Get code
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCode()
{
    return $this->code;
}       /**
 * Add communication
 *
 * @param Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\Communication $communication
 */
public function addCommunication(\Test\DatabaseBundle\Entity\Communication $communication)
{
    $this->communication[] = $communication;
}

/**
 * Get communication
 *
 * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getCommunication()
{
    return $this->ccommunication;
}       public function __construct()
{
    $this->communication = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

you said doctrine automatically check the object. Do you that , normally, doctrine execute the query and search, in the database, the current value of the object and pass it as the default choice?

With this I can modify my entity, but I don't know how to put my current entity Status value as the default value for the widget "entity". The method "getCodeOnly" search in the database the value of the attibut code of status (Complete, Cancelled, InProgress, Deleted) and always passed Complete as the default value. For exemple, if an entity as the value Cancelled, I want to put Cancelled as the default value when I use this form to modify my entity.

I cannot use getData and preferred_choice to have access to the status value because preferred_choice needs an array as parameter and not an entity.

I also tried to build an array with the different values of status and passed it to my form but du to several problem with my database, it failed.

If anyone have any infomation to solve this problem, i would be happy to see it.

Comment: In your controller, can you get the right status code of your entity Communication ? (var_dump($comm->getStatut()); exit;)

Comment: Yes i can. The thing is, if i put a text widget instead of a entity widget, the default value is the one in my database. But with the entity widget, the result of my query overwrite the right value. I want to put the value in the database as the "first" value of my choicelist

Comment: Just another question, are you using different EntityManagers on your project (one for read database, another one for write in the database, etc...) or by default just one ? I had a bug and it was caused because of master / slave em ^^

Comment: I use the same EntityManager for reading and writing. For those who can read French, i have found this, i'm triying this solution, i'll let you know if it works for me ^^ :http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1193899/php/bibliotheques-frameworks/symfony2/formulaire-entity-select/

Comment: Not the right solution. Using the 'entity' field is the good choice. Did you create the $communication; var in your Statut entity ?

Comment: yes, in my controller i can have access to the status from my communication and to the communication from my status. I don't know if an option like 'preferred_choice' exists for querybuilder but it's something like that i'm searching for.

Comment: Normally it does this automatically by checking the object in relation. It's thanks to doctrine, so perhaps you forgot something in the relation, which seems strange because you can get objects with getter and it seems to work fine :s However can you paste more code of your entities ?

Comment: i've just add setters and getters of my entities in my subject